# Read only user for Open Directory

Tags: open-directory

I need to authenticate against Open Directory on a linux box that has open-ldap installed. The program wants me to enter a username and password that can authenticate against OD. However, I do not want to provide my diradmin/password as its a read/write admin account.

How can I create a read-only user?